# Pygame problem or my problem? Instant Game Over when making python snake game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm pretty new to python and I am trying to make a simple python snake game with the pygame module but every time I load it up it starts the game over sequence and quits the game. There are no errors, its just this issue. I need help with this. Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import random

# Set up pygame.
pygame.init()

# Set up the window.
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Grenade Snake')

# Set up the colors.
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Set up the snake.
snake = []
snakeLength = 3
for i in range(0, snakeLength):
    snake.append((200, 200))

# Set up the apple.
apple = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
apple.fill(GREEN)
appleRect = apple.get_rect()
appleX = random.randint(0, 500)
appleY = random.randint(0, 400)
appleRect.topleft = (appleX, appleY)

# Set up movement variables.
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 10

# Set up the music.


# Set up the font.
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# Set up the score.
score = 0

# Set up game over text.
gameOverText = font.render('Game Over', True, WHITE)
gameOverRect = gameOverText.get_rect()
gameOverRect.center = (500 // 2, 400 // 2)

# Run the game loop.
while True:
    # Check for events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Change the keyboard variables.
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                moveDown = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            # Change the mouse button variables.
            if event.button == pygame.LEFT:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = False

    # Fill the background color.
    windowSurface.fill(BLACK)

    # Move the snake.
    if moveDown and snake[0][1] + 10 < 400:
        snake[0] = (snake[0][0], snake[0][1] + 10)
    if moveUp and snake[0][1] > 10:
        snake[0] = (snake[0][0], snake[0][1] - 10)
    if moveLeft and snake[0][0] > 10:
        snake[0] = (snake[0][0] - 10, snake[0][1])
    if moveRight and snake[0][0] + 10 < 500:
        snake[0] = (snake[0][0] + 10, snake[0][1])

    # Check if the snake has collied with itself.
    for snakeBody in snake[1:]:
        if snake[0][0] == snakeBody[0] and snake[0][1] == snakeBody[1]:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            windowSurface.blit(gameOverText, gameOverRect)
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(2)
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Check if the snake has eaten an apple.
    if snake[0][0] == appleRect.left and snake[0][1] == appleRect.top:
        # Play the sound effect.
        pickUpSound.play()

        # Increment the score.
        score = score + 1

        # The new head of the snake.
        snake.append((0, 0))

        # Move the apple.
        appleX = random.randint(0, 500)
        appleY = random.randint(0, 400)
        appleRect.topleft = (appleX, appleY)

    # Draw the snake.
    for position in snake:
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, pygame.Rect(position[0], position[1], 10, 10))

    # Draw the apple.
    windowSurface.blit(apple, appleRect)

    # Draw the score.
    scoreText = font.render(str(score), True, WHITE)
    windowSurface.blit(scoreText, (0, 0))

    # Draw the window onto the screen.
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Answer (score 2):

When you set up the snake:

```
snake = []
snakeLength = 3
for i in range(0, snakeLength):
    snake.append((200, 200))
```

you place the snake `head[0]` and rest of the snake on the same position `(200,200)`. Then during the first iteration it checks if the snake's head is on top of any part of the snake's body, and it is.